# modal appears on form submission even if the form is not validated

Tags: html, forms, validation, modal-dialog

I am working on a contact us form. After clicking on the submit button i want the form to be validated for example if text is entered in the mobile number field i want an error message to be displayed.
if all the data types in the form are correct i want a modal to be displayed which says thank you.
heres the code:

```
<form class="form">
              <div class="line"><label  style="font-size: 18px;"for="fname">First Name *: </label><input type="text" id="fname" required /></div>
              <div class="line"><label for="lname">Last Name *: </label><input type="text" id="lname" required /></div>
              <!-- You may want to consider adding a "confirm" password box also -->

              <div class="line"><label for="email">Email *: </label><input type="email" id="email"required /></div>
              <!-- Valid input types: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_form_input_types.asp -->
              <div class="line"><label for="tel">Mobile *: </label><input type="tel"pattern="[789][0-9]{9}" id="tel" required/></div>
              <div class="line"><label for="add">Address *: </label><input type="text" id="add" required/></div>
              <div class="line"><label for="ptc">Post Code *: </label><input type="number" maxlenght="6" id="ptc" required /></div>
              <div><button data-target="modal1" type="submit"class=" waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger">Submit<i class="material-icons right">send</i></button></div>

              <p>Note: Please make sure your details are correct before submitting form and that all fields marked with * are completed!.</p>
          </form>
```

below is the javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// the "href" attribute of .modal-trigger must specify the modal ID that   wants to be triggered
$('.modal-trigger').leanModal();
});
```

here is the modal structure.

```
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
<div class="modal-content">
<h4>Thank You</h4>
<p>Our Customer service team will contact you shortly</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green   btn-flat">OK</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using twitter bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

The problem about your code is that you are handling the wrong event. I don´t know what framework you are using but your button probably shows the modal when the button is clicked and not when the form is submitted. It would be better to watch for the submit event of the form.

```
(function($){
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.form').on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.modal-trigger').leanModal();//Show your modal?  
        });
      });

    })(jQuery);
```

Here is an example I prepared using Twitter bootstrap. I used your form and a the modal of the framework. The functionality must be very similar to the one you desire.

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('form.form').on('submit', function(e) { //Handle the submit event of the form
      e.preventDefault(); //This prevents the form from submitting, You might need to delete it in your actual code
      $('#myModal').modal('show'); //In bootstrap this is the function that shows the modal. It might differ on your actual code. 
    });
  });

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form class="form">
  <div class="line">
    <label style="font-size: 18px;" for="fname">First Name *:</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" required />
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <label for="lname">Last Name *:</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" required />
  </div>
  <!-- You may want to consider adding a "confirm" password box also -->

  <div class="line">
    <label for="email">Email *:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" required />
  </div>
  <!-- Valid input types: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_form_input_types.asp -->
  <div class="line">
    <label for="tel">Mobile *:</label>
    <input type="tel" pattern="[789][0-9]{9}" id="tel" required/>
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <label for="add">Address *:</label>
    <input type="text" id="add" required/>
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <label for="ptc">Post Code *:</label>
    <input type="number" maxlenght="6" id="ptc" required />
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit" class=" waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger">Submit</button>
  </div>

  <p>Note: Please make sure your details are correct before submitting form and that all fields marked with * are completed!.</p>
</form>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        your modal
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```